# Display Error when format date in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel.

I have date:

```
Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1577636272 {#912 ▼
  date: 2019-12-29 17:17:52.0 Europe/Warsaw (+01:00)
}
$userLastActivity = $userLastActivity->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

When I try convert it I have error:

```
Call to a member function format() on null
```

How can I repair it?

Comment: can you try `echo $userLastActivity; die();` and post the output?

Comment: hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. 
Could you please show dd($userLastActivity)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `$userLastActivity` is a date or carbon instance.
you can use `Carbon::parse` for date parse.

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse($userLastActivity)->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `$userLastActivity` may be `null` sometimes so you can use `optional` helper function like this:

```php
$userLastActivity = optional($userLastActivity)->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-optional